# How to run database insert query in for loop

Tags: database, for-loop, pouchdb

I am going to save data using for loops
after each iteration, I have some task to do ex doSomeWork()
but here this function iterates before query return any response,

I want to make this for loop as it should run doSomeTask function and next lop must iterate after query completion as my function depends on some unique value.

```
for (let i of data.rows) {
    if(i.doc.sync === false || i.doc.syncFail === true) 
    {
        PouchDb.post(i.doc).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            doSomeWork(response);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Do you get any error?

Comment: did not get any error, but I need is 'for' loop must wait until we get a response value

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `async/await` for what you want to achieve.

**Try this:**

```
for (let i of data.rows) {
    if(i.doc.sync === false || i.doc.syncFail === true) 
    {
        var response = await PouchDb.post(i.doc);
        console.log(response);
        doSomeWork(response);
    }
}
```